# How 'and' and 'or' work in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

Imagine I have a database for a large website which has a table called 'users' that has a large number of records. When I execute a query such as `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='John'` my understanding is that (ignoring caching etc.) the database would navigate the index and find the user(s) named John. Imagine this query returns 1 million results and I am only interested in users called John who are 25 years old, so I perform another query: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='John' AND age=25`

How does this work? does it loop through all the users named John and find only those who's age matches 25, or is there a better way of doing it? I assume this is database and storage engine specific so we can assume I am using MySQL with InnoDB.

Comment: from what I understand it will compare both for each row and not re evaluate for each AND/OR condition... if you were to use a HAVING clause that would be another story

Comment: You can check such a thing using query planner

Answer (score 3):

The answer is -- you're not supposed to ask this question.  In a declarative language like SQL you describe the result desired and the processing engine determines the optimal way to produce the result.  It may take different paths to get to the result depending on seemingly minor differences in the request, or the method used may change from version to version of the product, or even based on some factor completely unrelated to the product (available memory or disk space, for instance).

That said, the following is true of *most* SQL databases in *most* cases:

1. The database will use only one index in evaluating a WHERE clause.
2. If more than one index *could* be used to evaluate the WHERE clause the database will use statistics about the cardinality (distribution of values) in each index to select the "best" one.
3. If there is an index built from more than one column, and the *head* column(s) of that index are present in the filter conditions of the WHERE clause, that index can possibly be used to filter by multiple columns in a single index.

So, in your example, most databases would use indexes on either age or name to do the first-level filtering, then scan the resulting records to do the second level of filtering.  The only exception would be if you had a compound index on (name, age) or (age, name) in which case only an index scan would be needed to find the records.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE username = 'John' AND age = 25;
```

Then the optimal index is `users(username, age)` or `users(age, username)`.  With this index, the matching records can be found just by looking them up in the index.

As for what happens if you only have an index on `username`.  It would typically look up the rows with "John" in the `username` column.  It would then fetch the records from the data pages and continue the filtering based on the data on the pages.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have indexes on both columns, it generally examines the statistics of the data itself to choose an option that reduces the cardinality of the result set as quickly as possible.

For example, if 20% of people are aged 25 but only 3% are called John, it will get the Johns first then strip out those who are not aged 25.

If you have a composite key made up of *both* columns, then that should be even faster, since there's no "stripping" involved at all.

Bottom line, it comes down to the DB engine understanding the makeup of the data and choosing the best execution plan based on that. That's why it's often good to re-calculate statistics periodically, as the data may change.